# angularjs state provider use other values besides id in url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-routing, angularjs-controller

I am using `$stateProvider` to map out the routes for my app.  I want the urls to be meaningful so that rather than the id coming through in the url I get the date, category and title for a news app.

Currently I can get the state to load the desired template when I do

```
    .state('viewArticle', {
        url: '/news/:articleId',
        templateUrl: 'view-article.html'
    })
```

I get `http://www.example.com/#!/news/5517374f286ff5ba79037568`
I want to get the same view loaded with my article showing with the url `http://www.example.com/#!/news/2015-04-04/weather/tomorrow`

I can acheive this when I hard code the url in the state

```
    .state('viewArticle', {
        url: '/news/2015-04-04/weather/tomorrow',
        templateUrl: 'view-article.html'
    })
```

But I can't work out how to pass multiple params into the url from my data.
Is this possible?  How can this best be achieved.

This is what I have come up with but have had no success.

```
    //angular.module().config
    .state('viewArticle', {
        //url: '/news/:articleId',
        //url: '/news/2015-04-04/weather/tomorrow',            
        url: '/news/:year/:category/:title',
        templateUrl: 'view-article.html'
    })

    //view-article.html (this seems ok as it works when state hard coded)
    go('/' + article.date + '/' + article.category + '/' + article.title

    //controller
    $scope.go = function(path) {
        $location.path( path );
    };
```

Comment: You mean `go('/news/' + ar....`, right?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv yes

Comment: You probably need to `$scope.$apply()` after `$location.path`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use `$state.go()` of `angular-ui-router` instead of `$location.path`

**Method**

```
$state.go('viewArticle',{year: article.date, category: article.category, title: article.title });
```